# Find excluded files in Visual Studio using >of (Open File) or Resharper Go To File commands?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, resharper

Is there an option to allow either Open File of Resharpers Go To File feature to include excluded files in the search?

Answer (score 1):

You can use Find  in files:
<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>F</kbd>
and search the specific folder.
To open the first location press <kbd>F8</kbd> and continue through the list.

Comment: Thanks Markoo, but I'm actually trying to open the file directly, to locate the file in solution explorer.

Comment: So you want to automatically open all files that are found with the search term?
I can imagine this would potentially crash Visual Studio.
The next best thing you can do is start pressing F8, which opens the next location & Shift + F8 to go back in the list.